# Uninstall and reinstall raspberry pi desktop on chromebook

Tags: linux, port, sd-card, chromebook

I have a 4GB Raspberry Pi which stopped booting recently. I want to uninstall and reinstall the os so it will boot up fresh. I don't have an adapter, but I do have a chromebook which has an sd card port. I want to uninstall and reinstall the os on the chromebook, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install Raspberry PI OS on an SD card using only a Chromebook.

[Put Raspberry PI OS on SD Card](https://willhaley.com/blog/setup-raspberry-pi-chromebook/)

> It is possible to configure a WiFi enabled Raspberry Pi using only a
> Chromebook and your WiFi access point. This can be done headless (no
> monitor required) and results in a Raspberry Pi with WiFi and ssh
> enabled so that you can control it from your Chromebook.
>
> Requirements:
>
> A WiFi router/access point (AP) for which you know the password
> Chromebook SD/microSD Card Reader (built in to many Chromebooks)
> Raspberry Pi with integrated WiFi Raspbian OS image .zip file
> downloaded to the Chromebook Chromebook Recovery Utility, an App
> provided by Google Text, a text editor App for Chrome OS Connect the
> SD/microSD card to your Chromebook.
>
> Launch the Recovery Utility and click the gear icon in the upper right
> hand corner. Select the Use local image menu option.

Comment: Thanks, I really hope this works.

Comment: What you need is in my post, but take time to read through the entire article (link in my answer) and absorb it all.

Comment: oh, and also, that chrome extension, will it uninstall os on sd card too?

Comment: The Chrome extension should not interfere according to the article. You might wish to wipe the card clear first.